# Is firebase function's execution speed consistent?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm interested in using firebase functions.
I can't find any reference about execution speed of firebase functions.

So the question is: If I write a function (which is independent of network and outer resources), will it take nearly the same execution time every time I execute it? Is the execution speed consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each instance that Cloud Functions spins up to run your code will be an instance of the same container on the same hardware. Since there are no parallel executions of functions on the same instance, the functions all have access to the complete resources of their instance while they run.

The only way to change the performance is by changing the memory that is available in the container (which in turn also changes the CPU), but this is a configuration that you control and it applies to all instances of your function that start after you change it. For an overview of these instance types, see the table on the [Cloud Functions pricing page](https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing).

And as Doug pointed out, if Cloud Functions needs to provision a new container for a function invocation there will be a delay that is known as a cold-start while the container is being set up.

Comment: And don't forget that cold start times will cause apparent performance variations between invocations.